# Retrieving multiple records from sendable DE

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I have a DE which can contain one or multiple rows for the same customer & this depends on the number of products they subscribe in an application.
We want to email them the status of these products as and when they become Active.

Example DE below

[image]

I looked up Adam's blog and am using the following code.

```
var @rows, @row, @rowCount, @numRowsToReturn, @lookupValue, @i

set @lookupValue = AttributeValue("NAME")
set @numRowsToReturn = 0
set @rows = LookupOrderedRows("Test_welcome_rahul",@numRowsToReturn,"Product desc, Account_Status__c asc","NAME", @lookupValue)
set @rowCount = rowcount(@rows)

if @rowCount > 0 then

  for @i = 1 to @rowCount do

    var @Product, @Status
    set @row = row(@rows,@i) /* get row based on counter */
    set @Product = field(@row,"Product")
    set @Status = field(@row,"Account_Status__c")

    ]%%

   

    %%[ 
  next @i ]%%

%%[ else ]%%

No rows found

%%[ endif ]%%
```

In the email, I have a table like below

[image]

The outcome i am getting is below

[image]

The desired outcome is below. (assuming the first two rows in the DE are the same contact)

[image]

So essentially i want the query to lookup the **Name** column then display the **Product** and its respective **Status** in the same row. 1 x row per product & if there are multiple products then it will be multiple rows etc

I have tried a few variations with the code but not making much progress.
Any help on this is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to output the table rows inside your loop:

```ampscript
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <td>Product</td>
    <td>Status</td>
  </tr>

%%[

var @rows, @row, @rowCount, @numRowsToReturn, @lookupValue, @i

set @lookupValue = AttributeValue("NAME")
set @numRowsToReturn = 0
set @rows = LookupOrderedRows("Test_welcome_rahul",@numRowsToReturn,"Product desc, Account_Status__c asc","NAME", @lookupValue)
set @rowCount = rowcount(@rows)

if @rowCount > 0 then

  for @i = 1 to @rowCount do

    var @Product, @Status
    set @row = row(@rows,@i) /* get row based on counter */
    set @Product = field(@row,"Product")
    set @Status = field(@row,"Account_Status__c")

    ]%%

    <tr>
       <td>%%=v(@product)=%%</td>
       <td>%%=v(@status)=%%</td>
    </tr>

    %%[ 
  next @i ]%%

%%[ else ]%%

    <tr>
       <td>no rows found</td>
       <td></td>
    </tr>

%%[ endif ]%%

</table>
```

Comment: Thank you Adam. This code works as intended.